# How to get the ID of a just created record in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.3 for one of my projects and I need to get the ID of a record just saved in the database.

I have something like the code below to save a record in the database:

```
n = MyData.objects.create(record_title=title, record_content=content)
n.save()
```

The ID of the record just saved auto-increments. Is there a way to get that ID and use it somewhere else in my code?

Comment: The line `n.save()` is unnecessary here, as `MyData.objects.create` automatically saves the new instance.

Comment: my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25807622/3762142 will get you id in html page..

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use `n.id` after the save.

See "[Auto-incrementing primary keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)".

Comment: When I save data using form in views then how to access id that is just saves by froms object?

Comment: It should be `n.pk` since it will be id only if you didn't add a primary key yourself, or added one and named it id.

Comment: @JamesO how to get or resolve this id as a model instance.

Answer (score 64):

It would be `n.pk`.

To quote "[Model.pk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.pk)":

> Regardless of whether you define a
>   primary key field yourself, or let
>   Django supply one for you, each model
>   will have a property called pk. It
>   behaves like a normal attribute on the
>   model, but is actually an alias for
>   whichever attribute is the primary key
>   field for the model. You can read and
>   set this value, just as you would for
>   any other attribute, and it will
>   update the correct field in the model.

Comment: nice find. This indicates that calling `.pk` is probably considered the "best practice" since it references either the default id or a custom id.

Comment: the link above goes to the in-dev version of django.  v 1.7-v1.10 says the same thing, though: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.pk  not sure about before v1.7

Answer (score 12):

The ID will be automatically updated in your model, so immediately after your `n.save()` line you can read `n.id` and it will be populated.

Comment: Trying this without success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160852/pk-not-set-to-model-entity-after-save-in-django

Answer (score 11):

Remove save() and get pk directly:

```
n = MyData.objects.create(record_title=title, record_content=content)
n.pk
```

Answer (score 7):

If someone reading this question and after check the other answers still having problems accessing the id after the creation of the object.
Be sure you don't define `id` as an Integer in your model.  If you decide to declare it anyways, use `Autofield`  but you don't need to, It is for free with `models.Model`

```
#No
class TestModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    something...


#Ok
class TestModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    something...

#Ok
class TestModel(models.Model):
    something...
```

if you do define `id` as Integer, `TestModel.objects.create(` or with `save()` will return None.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with accessing the id. In Django 3.0.5, this is how I accessed the id. Using your example and variable name, see below:

```
instance = n.save()
# return the id
instance[0].id
```

The variable 'instance' above is a list. Accessing id in the methods described above returns an AttributeError ("object has no attribute 'id'") in Django 3.

This answer applies when using `modelformset_factory`. This is true when creating a Form class from a Django model as described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: its not working, it got an error that object type is not sub-scriptable