# Get ID of Django record after it has been created in a ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to get the ID of the record created during a Django REST Framework API call so I can use it in a bit of code I need to run as a result of the API call.

In brief I am uploading an image file using a POST call to my Photo model and I want, as a result of that POST call (and while processing it in the ViewSet), to insert the ID of the Photo record that has just been created into a record in another model (in my case called the Item model).

My question is whereabouts in the PhotoViewSet can I access the ID of the created record?

My Photo model looks like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="userphotos/", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The associated serializer looks like this:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'photo', 'item')
```

And the associated ModelViewSet looks like this:

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        the_itemID = self.request.data['item_id']
        the_userID = self.request.data['user_id']
        the_user = User.objects.get(pk=the_userID)
        the_item = Item.objects.get(pk=the_itemID)

        serializer.save(user=the_user, item=the_item, photo=self.request.data.get('photo'))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253611/django-how-to-get-the-id-of-the-record-just-saved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `serializer.save()` should return the instance that has just been create.

`instance = serializer.save(...)`

`instance_id = instance.id`

Comment: it is not working in my case. I have almost similar question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534706/access-auto-increment-primary-field-value-during-creation-of-a-record-with-djang)

Answer (score 3):

`serializer.save()` returns a Photo object, at which point you can access its id.

Comment: Is there any way I can just return the id or exclude some fields?